# java memory leak fixing

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

I am looking for some memory leaks in java programs.

I have a class named `ABCConfiguration` and `ABCConfigurationInfo` classes. `ABCConfigurationInfo` is a class which have some `private static final String` constants and keeping a private `TreeMap` object. `ABCConfiguration` is a config class which keeps an object of `ABCConfigurationInfo` class (`private ABCConfigurationInfo fInfo;`).

When executed the program multiple times I found (using MAT) that the the objects of `ABCConfigurationInfo` keeps increasing. I don't have a fix.

That is I have changed the

```
private ABCConfigurationInfo fInfo
```

to

```
private static ABCConfigurationInfo fInfo.
```

After this, I have checked the objects of `ABCConfigurationInfo` after multiple times of execution. It is become stable and one object is creating. Is it a real fix? Could you please advice me.

I know that, with these much information it is hard to tell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: its a fix only if static suits your scenario :)
try adding your code so we can help you find the problem

Comment: I am surprised your configuration is so complex that it takes up a significant amount of memory.  Does this really make much of a difference in your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can afford having the same fInfo instance on all your ABCConfiguration objects then its a valid fix.

Answer (score 1):

In your original version, there is one `ABCConfigurationInfo` for every `ABCConfiguration`. In your `static` version, there's a single `ABCConfigurationInfo` for the whole application; it's shared by all the `ABCConfiguration` objects. We don't know whether that's appropriate or not -- only you do. It's a big change, though, so you certainly need to be aware of what you're doing.